# prefix to infix notation in c++

Tags: c++, prefix, infix-notation

i'm trying to convert an prefix expression to its infix form with the code below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
 
using namespace std;
 
bool isOperand(char c)
{
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
 
string PrefixToInfix(string prefix)
{
    stack<string> s;
    for (int i = prefix.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (isOperand(prefix[i])) {
            string op(1, prefix[i]);
            s.push(op);
        }
        else {
            string op1 = s.top();
            s.pop();
            string op2 = s.top();
            s.pop();
            s.push("(" + op1 + prefix[i] + op2 + ")");
        }
    }

    return s.top();
}
 
int main()
{
    string infix, prefix;
    cin >> prefix;
    infix = PrefixToInfix(prefix);
    cout << infix << endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

It works well for the expression `..*+abc+d+efg`, the output is `((((a+b)*c).(d+(e+f))).g)` and its right. When i input `+.*bbba+++b++bb*b+bb+bba` i get `(((b*b).b)+a)` but the output should be `((bb)*(ba)+(((b+((b+b)+b*))+(b+b))+(bb+a)))*`.
Can someone help me understand the reason behind the error?

Comment: For testing and debugging, it helps to hard-code the simplest failing input into the program itself. Then you should use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement wile monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: To add to what Someprogrammerdude said: Start with much smaller test cases and work up to longer ones, making sure to try out each path in your program one at a time ... in other words, start with a very small but stable foundation of code that you _know_ works and build on that step by step so that you have confidence in each result.

Comment: is `((bb)*(ba)+(((b+((b+b)+b*))+(b+b))+(bb+a)))*` a valid infix expression?

Comment: What is supposed to be `bb` in the infix expression? As you have no name separator in your syntax, I would assume that variables can only be one character long.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the problem just changing `prefixToInfix()` to:

```cpp
string PrefixToInfix(string prefix)
{
    stack<string> s;
    for (int i = prefix.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (isOperand(prefix[i])) {
            string op(1, prefix[i]);
            s.push(op);
        }
        else {
            if(prefix[i] == "*") {
              string op1 = s.top();
              s.pop();
              s.push("(" + op1 + prefix[i] + ")");
            } else {
              string op1 = s.top();
              s.pop();
              string op2 = s.top();
              s.pop();
              s.push("(" + op1 + prefix[i] + op2 + ")");
            }
        }
    }

    return s.top();
}
```